# How should we tag MMT?

Tags: discussion, tags

The game [*Mukashi Mukashi aru Tokoro ni Totetsumonaku Naka no Warui Twintail no Shimai Himesama ga Irasshaimashita to sa*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/mukashi-mukashi-tokoro/info) is obviously way too long to even conceivably fit in a tag. There have been some back-and-forth on how to tag it, [now that we actually have a question on it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6269/how-do-i-get-past-a-cliff). How should we go about tagging it?

Some examples that have been proposed, or are derived from propositions.

- **[mmt]**: MMT is the official abbreviation used by the creators of the game, both in the files and on their website.
- **[mmatntnnwtnshgits]**: What would be produced if the full name, as transliterated, were converted into a direct acronym.
- **[mmttnwtshi]**: A shortened acronym that removes those minor words.
- **[mukashi-mukashi-tokoro]**: A direct expansion of the official abbreviation. The technical expansion is mukashi-mukashi-aru-tokoro, but that is 26 characters and thus too long.
- **[mukashimukashiarutokoro]**: As above, but without linebreaks. This is more accurate but less readable, but technically the title doesn't have linebreaks anyway. This is 23 characters.

Comment: Question: are tags restricted to ASCII characters? or do we have UTF-16?

Comment: @tzenes I just tried adding a "むかしむかし" tag and it did not go through.

Comment: @Grace darn.  That would have been so cool.

Comment: @tzenes There was a [related proposal regarding diacritics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58846/implement-tag-diacritics-with-automatic-synonyms), but looking at Jeff's answer there it seems there's no chance for non-ASCII support.

Comment: @Grace sadly he doesn't include UTF-16 support for synonyms which would be nice...  At least then you could enter one and get the other.

Comment: @Grace Don't despair, eventually [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2912/persian-information-technology-and-computer) will go through. It'll be _fun_, it's a pity I won't get to see the fireworks.

Comment: The tag wiki got [lost](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/mukashi-mukashi-tokoro/info)  as the question was retagged.

Comment: @badp I have updated the link now to the current (and vastly improved) wiki. Thanks again for pointing it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think we should consider the google query which would bring a person to this question, our goal is to provide meaningful answers which can be indexed and searched.

- MMT -> 17 million largely unrelated
- mmatntnnwtnshgits -> none
- mmttnwtshi -> none with a spelling correction
- mukashi-mukashi-tokoro -> 30,000 results, largely related
- mukashimukashiarutokoro -> Corrected to mukashi mukashi aru tokoro, 27,000 results largely related

Based on this, I would suggest the two latter ones are what we should decide between as they are the most likely ones to bring a user to this question.

Between the two, the former is my personal preference as it conforms to the word-word style we are accustom to, but I would be pleased with either.

For reference mukashi mukashi aru has 160,000 results, but not nearly as related (eg. it links to "mukashi mukashi, aru dokoro")

Comment: Which means we should use "mukashi-mukashi-tokoro".

Comment: It's been almost a month, and the comment from @badp has 5 votes while my post only has 3. So we're going to use [mukashi-mukashi-tokoro]. I can stomach the inaccuracy just to settle this for now.

Comment: @GraceNote - 6 years later, the game name seems to have disappeared. Should we re-add it?

Answer (score 4):

I originally planned to support [mmt]. But in light of [tzenes' stats](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-should-we-tag-mmt/911#911), I'm more in favour of **[mukashimukashiarutokoro]**. The main reason is accuracy - the version with dashes looks nicer to English speaking but is incorrect. It would be the equivalent of tagging *The Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past* as [legend-zelda-link-past].

I had a long winded argument about how no one who doesn't possess at least cursory knowledge of Japanese will ever remember how むかしむかしあるところ is pronounced, and thereby know how to tag the game. But this is easily solved by just adding an [mukashimukashiarutokoro] ← [mmt] synonym. MMT remains the official abbreviation and the easiest form of allowing English speakers to actually refer to the game. MMT is also how it is already commonly referred to in the import gamer circles. So if we are to use the long name tag, it is *crucial* that we have this synonym, because it is otherwise impossible to expect all users to even know *what* to look for in the autocomplete.

Also note that a translated version for the tag is a bad idea due to the lack of a consistent official translation.

Comment: I completely agree with this.